# Geometry nodes rain simulation not preserving saved frame after reopening Blender

Tags: animation, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

As you can ***see in*** [***this video***](https://streamable.com/zgi1j4), I have two geometry nodes modifiers, made with this [Rain Generator](https://jepe.gumroad.com/l/raingenerator). One of them controls falling rain and the other controls rain splashes on objects.

After letting the animation play, I picked a frame that looked good for me (57, since there were no rain drops in front of the character's face). There were also a lot of rain splashes, which I wanted for my render.

However, when I save my file with the desired frame selected, close and then re-open the scene, the frame is completely different. The raindrops are in different positions and the splashes haven't been fully generated yet, and the only way to fix it is by going back to frame 0 and letting the whole thing play out again.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I am trying to render the image on a render farm, which means that I can't just go back to frame 0 and let it play, I have to upload the blend file and let it render as-is.

Comment: Having had a quick glance at the nodes used I imagine that's because both the Rain Zone and Rain splash nodes use Random Value nodes which means that the result is going to be different each time you load the Blend file.

Comment: Nope, I just didn't bake the simulation nodes... ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I just didn't bake the simulation nodes... ‍♂️

[image]

Comment: Ah ok. I was going to suggest that, but can you actually use cache files on a render farm? - I've never had occasion to use one so have no idea if they accept them.

Comment: I guess it depends on the service, actually mine isn't really a render farm, it's more like "cloud rendering". Thanks btw!